# detect and count the number of star symbol in opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

I need to count the occurrence of the stars at the right bottom corner in the image, I read this article
[Template Matching](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html)
and used the following code to find the stars but My code doesn't work for detecting the stars in the image.

What changes should I make in the code?

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img_rgb = cv.imread('page.png')
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv.imread('star_temp.png', 0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
res = cv.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8
loc = np.where(res >= threshold)
print(res)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv.imwrite('res.png', img_rgb)
```

star_temp.png

[image]

page.png

[image]

Comment: In template matching, the template must be the same size and orientation as the symbols you are trying to match. If that is the case, adjust your threshold and use non-maxima suppression to avoid too many matches of the same symbol.  Please search Google and/or this forum for many examples of template matching in Python and OpenCV.  For example, see https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/03/29/multi-template-matching-with-opencv/.  I suggest using TM_SQDIFF or TM_CORR_NORMED, not TM_COEFF_anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your template is bigger than the actual star on the image. Template matching **is not scale invariant**, so you need to be careful and match an almost same-size image. I cropped  this from your target image:

[image: 1]

This is the full working snippet:

```
import cv2

# image path
path = "D://opencvImages//"

# Reading images in default mode:
targetImage = cv2.imread(path + "d6tu1.png")
templateImage = cv2.imread(path + "starTemplate.png")

# Deep copy for results:
targetImageCopy = targetImage.copy()

# Convert RGB to grayscale:
grayscaleImage = cv2.cvtColor(targetImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayscaleTemplate = cv2.cvtColor(templateImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Perform template match:
matchResult = cv2.matchTemplate(grayscaleImage, grayscaleTemplate, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
# Set matching minimum score:
threshold = 0.9
loc = np.where( matchResult >= threshold)

# Look for possible matches:
matchesCounter = 0
w, h = grayscaleTemplate.shape[::-1]

for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(targetImageCopy, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)

    # increase number of matches:
    matchesCounter +=1

    cv2.imshow("Matches", targetImageCopy)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

print("Number of matches: "+str(matchesCounter))
```

You end up with this result:

[image]

```
Number of matches: 3
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, it works. but the image will be taken from the camera on mobile so it should be a size variant, do you have suggestions to deal with it?

Comment: please edit your question to show a _representative_ picture. that revelation will make the task significantly more complex.